# Open .doc located in webDAV server directly into Word

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, webdav

You see I am trying to edit a file that’s in the WebDAV server, but I am doing this through ASP.NET and C# in a DotNetNuke Website. I saw the code for the Sample Server Browser
included with the ITHIT WebDAV SDK, where I saw a functionality similar to the one I require , but its a local Windows Application and it uses Process.Run() to open Word. This process will not work for my case however since that would
cause the process to be executed on the server (w3wp.exe process) and not the clients machine. My
questions is how would I implement this capability, you can take a look at their [Ajax Browser](http://www.ajaxbrowser.com/) for an example; right click any document and "Edit Document" appears, which causes Word to open up. How can I open a specific word document from the WebDAV
server directly into word? Am I going to have to use JavaScript? If So, how can
I pass the location of the file as a parameter?

Comment: lol thanks for clearing that up Cedric :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To open a Microsoft Office documents from your web page, you will need to use JavaScript. You will need to program FFWinPlugin in case of Chrome, FireFox and Safari, or SharePoint.OpenDocuments ActiveX in case of Internet Explorer. Note that your server must be a Class 2 WebDAV server.

You can find more information [here](http://www.webdavsystem.com/server/documentation/ms_office_read_only).

Comment: Thank you very much @ITHitWebDAV, I appreciate the support you provide for your product. Just a quick question though, do FFWinPlugin and the Sharepoint.OpenDocuments require additional add-ons in the client browser? If Yes, Then How does the ajaxbrowser achieve this without requiring me to download a plugin? Does Sharepoint.OpenDocuments require me to install the Sharepoint SDK, if not how can I access their methods ( a little confused about that) ??

Comment: I am trying to use the OWSSUPP.dll associated with Sharepoint.OpenDocuments however I receive this error `Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {9203C2CB-1DC1-482D-967E-597AFF270F0D} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).` I can't figure out what I need to reference , or in fact how to even change my target platform! How can I solve this issue?!

Comment: FFWinPlugin and Sharepoint.OpenDocuments are installed by Microsoft Office and registered as a web browser add-on or ActiveX in case of IE. You do not need to manually download, install or register this components. They are ready to be used from JavaScript. You do not need to program OWSSUPP.dll directly, in a COM manner.

Comment: By calling `document.getElementById("winFirefoxPlugin")` should I be able to access its members through lets say Intellisense? I don't believe I am properly loading the object on to my page...would it be the same procedure for an .ascx control for DotnetNuke?

Comment: Finally got this to work! You **MUST** pass the location of the document as a URL, it cannot be a physical path even if that phyisical path is a network drive. Also I used `<object id="winFirefoxPlugin" type="application/x-sharepoint" width="0" height="0" style="visibility: hidden;"></object>` **AND the JavaScript WAS** `document.getElementById("winFirefoxPlugin").EditDocument("http://localhost:9658/TEST/WebDAV.doc");`

Answer (score 0):

To open document on client side you need javascript e.g.:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   window.open('http://www.usability.gov/templates/docs/u-test_plan_template.doc')
</script>
```

This is probably the way used by Ajax Browser the problem is that then file is downloaded to local computer and when you update it, it is necessary to upload it back again.

Comment: Yea see, this is what I wanted to avoid and it is the point of the webDAV Server. But I have figured out that in Internet Explorers case I would use Sharepoint.OpenDocuments and in any other browsers case the FFWinPlugin. I just have to figure out how to utilize them, but thank you for your input sir.